# Azure "Text-To-Speech" returns "Invalid CID or language". What does it mean?

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to post to Azure text-to-speech service. I have already acquired the access token and now I'm trying to make a call to convert text to speech (using Best HTTP in Unity):

```
            HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(new Uri(APIEndpointURL), HTTPMethods.Post, _GotTextToSpeechResponse);

        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/ssml+xml");
        request.AddHeader("X-Microsoft-OutputFormat", "raw-16khz-16bit-mono-pcm");
        request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "My app name");

        request.RawData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world!");
        request.Send();
```

This returns a status code 400 with the following:

> {"Message":"Invalid CID or language"}"

Documentation says that if I don't define language but just send text, it should use the default voice. Then, there's the "User-Agent" that should be "Application name". The documentation doesn't say if this should be predefined somewhere or what this refers to.

What could the error mean and how to fix it? Am I doing wrong when I'm posting as "Raw data"? It says I should post the text in the body of the request.

Comment: What is your `APIEndpointURL` value?

Comment: It is https://westeurope.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that are not clear in the documentation.

If you have a detailed look to the sample provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-apis?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#text-to-speech-api):
[image: sample from doc]

### Endpoint

You want to do some `text-to-speech` feature (generate the voice for your `Hello world!` text), but you are calling a `stt` (speech-to-text) endpoint made for speaker recognition:

```
https://westeurope.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1
```

To use `tts`, the endpoint should be in the same format as the sample:

```
https://westeurope.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1
```

### Content of the request

Regarding the fact that you don't want to use `SSML`, the doc states:

> Text is sent as the body of an HTTP POST request. It can be plain text
> (ASCII or UTF-8) or Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML) format
> (UTF-8). Plain text requests use the Speech Service's default voice
> and language. With SSML you can specify the voice and language.

So I tried the following: changing the content-type from `"application/ssml+xml"` to  `"text/plain"`. But in that case, I got:

```
Error 400 Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

It looks like it is a common error when parsing xml, so it looks like there is a bug somewhere here, and I can't find a sample in the doc which is using TTS and without ssml.

Someone posted a question regarding that in the Feedback section of the page (under Next Steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-apis?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#next-steps))

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I changed the endpoint, but I still get status code 400 and no error in the body, no matter what I send there (plain or xml). What could it possibly be? I accepted your answer anyway because it answered my original question. However, I still can't get the tts to work for some reason.

Comment: It's working with SSML and a voice, I seriously doubt about the fact that it is working currently with plain text... I will follow the comment on Feedback section, or create an issue at Microsoft side because you're right, there is something incorrect here

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry - I am trying with the given test content: "<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'><voice xml:lang='en-US' xml:gender='Female' name = 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, ZiraRUS)' > Microsoft Speech Service Text - to - Speech API </ voice ></ speak > " and using application/ssml+xml. So I should have the exact same parameters as in the sample. But I still get code 400 and no explanation.

Comment: This one is working on my side: "<speak version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'><voice name='Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, ZiraRUS)'>Microsoft Speech Service Text-to-Speech API</voice></speak>"

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting a response with your string. :)

Comment: I don't know if they changes some specs, your string used to work until now, but a few days ago, it stopped working and started giving error 400. Out product is already in closed beta so of course it's good that this happened now and now when it's already in production.

I'm trying to use this string and I get error 400 back:
<speak version='1.0' xmlns='w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'><voice name='Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (fi-FI, HeidiRUS)'>My text</voice></speak>

Comment: No error detail provided? Did you try to add gender also, as it seems to be indicated in the doc (but based on our previous discussions it was working without)

Comment: I tried tweaking the string, adding gender and replacing single-quotes with double quotes, but didn't work:
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="https://w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="fi-FI" xml:gender="Female"><voice name="Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (fi-FI, HeidiRUS)">Text.</voice></speak>

The only error I get is:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request

Comment: Since it's another error, I'll post it as a new question. Thanks for your help so far. :)